# Core Plot :Move only Data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have created a scatter graph with three plot spaces. One for two y-axis each and one for the x-axis. I am able to show data for both y-axis. However now i want to move only the data,i.e. two line and not the two y-axis.Only the data and x-axis should move.

I have tried allowUserinteraction property. However is I enable it for x-axis, x axis moves without the data. If i enable it for both/either of axis, y axis also moves with data and scale of y-axis is not visible all the time. Can someone help pleas.e This is my first work with core plot.

I will add code if required.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since each plot space has both x and y ranges, I would just use two plot spaces for this situation. Use the same `xRange` for both plot spaces and assign the x-axis to one of them.

The easiest way to make them scroll only in the X direction is to set the `globalYRange` to the same range as the `yRange` for both plot spaces. Set `allowsUserInteraction` to YES for both plot spaces. If you need to change the `yRange` later, set the `globalYRange` to nil before you change the `yRange` and reset it afterwards. If you ever update the X range manually, be sure to always set it on both plot spaces.